# How to install Android SDK r21 with compatible platform-tools and packages

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

For an old Unity project I need Android SDK r21. I can successfully install it from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r21-windows.exe).

Unfortunately I cannot install the platform-tools r19.0.1 from the SDK manager (Package cannot be used due to error: platform-tools folder is missing aapt.exe ...).

Apparently the SDK r21 is incompatible with platform-tools r19.0.1. Unfortunately I am unable to download an older version or the individual Platform SDKs that I need for the Google APIs.

I guess I need an older version of the repository.xml, but I have no idea how to find it.

Any advice?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how about updating instead of sticking to the older version

Comment: I would love to, but that would mean updating Unity, which would mean updating 2D Toolkit, which would mean dealing with a lot of incompatible API changes. And I just need a build of an old work project for presentation...

Answer (score 0):

Download from google repository the platform tools version you want to downgrade to (for instance: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-macosx.zip), and extract it in your SDK folder.

You can also try using  http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html